# how to get value from a function that returns object in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am using math commons library but it turns out that when I want a function to **return an Double**, the intellij idea automatically corrects it to an object.

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.TDistribution


// TDistribution  --> It doesn't allow me to change to Double
fun calculo(a:Double): TDistribution {

    val distf = TDistribution(28.0,a)
    return distf
}

fun main(args: Array<String>){

    val ko = calculo(0.95)
    println(ko)
}
```

return it

```
org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.TDistribution@404b9385
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function returns `TDistribution`. To return `Double` you need something like this:

```
fun calculo(a:Double): Double {
    val distf = TDistribution(28.0,a)
    return distf.getNumericalMean()
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val ko = calculo(0.95)
    println(ko)
}
```

Comment: hello, but for some reason it returns 0.0, do you know what I'm wrong about?

Comment: @royer It is another issue. I suggest you to create a new question.